How to find digital patch-clamp recordings of isolated action potentials ideally in axons?
I'm looking for high resolution (e.g. 40kHz) patch-clamp recordings of isolated action potentials for data analysis.
I red somewhere in a scientific article (lost the reference) the claim that the area of the depolarization is the same as the hyperpolarization. I would like to verify if it's true and do other analysis if possible.

I can't think of any reason this would be true by anything but coincidence. It would also vary quite a bit by species. It would be easy to use simulated data from e.g. the NEURON simulation environment, there should be lots of axon simulations available that are based upon real data.

@BryanKrause Thank you for answering. I checked with the Hodgkin & Huxley model and it was indeed wrong. The difference is a factor two. But the AP with the HH model looks a bit weird. I was expecting that the hyperpolarization would be smoother.

What do you mean by "smoother"? If you're looking at the classic HH model, by the way, this is based on the "squid giant axon" which has quite different physiology than, say, a mammalian neuron (but also is quite literally giant so is much more amenable to patch clamp!).

@BryanKrause yes, I know, it's so far the best I could find. For the few graphics I could see, it seem more or less valid.
